# How to get selected dropdown value in scriptlet

Tags: java, jsp

```
<select name="userSelected">
            <option value="-1">---Select---</option>
            <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user" varStatus="status">
                <option value="${user.userId}">${user.userName}</option>
            </c:forEach>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/viewExpense/userSelected/<%=-1%>'">view</button>
```

when a user selects any value from dropdown then we can get the corresponging value using the name attribute (in this case name is "userSelected"). But how I can append this value in the href url above using that scriptlet. Someone help!!!

Comment: You want to jump onto the same page ?

Comment: yes... actually am displaying a dropdown, when a user selects any value then as per that value I want to show a table with its corresponding value

Comment: Any reason why not to use javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you are  linking to an anchor on a page you need to put a `#` in front of the anchor.

Try This

```
 $("#yourDropdown").change(function () { 
   var selectedValue = $('#yourDropdown option:selected').val();
   $("a").attr('href','#'+selectedValue); // just Append # tag before value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

```
<select id="userSelected">
      ----------
      ----------
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="submitPage();">view</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function submitPage() {
        var elm = document.getElementById("userSelected");
        var strVal = elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].value;
        window.location.href = '/viewExpense/userSelected/' + strVal;
    }
</script>
```

If possible, you try the same thing using JQuery.

```
<select id="userSelected">
    --------
    --------
</select>

<button id="submitButton">view</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submitButton').on('click', function() {
            window.location.href = '/viewExpense/userSelected/' + $('#userSelected :selected').text();;
        });
    });
</script>
```